# how to change button class when i click on it using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

so I am using Jquery to try and change bootstrap buttons classes when I click on them using the `toggleClass` but the problem is I only can toggle between only 2 classes and that ***not*** what I want, I want to toggle between at least 5 classes or even more each time I click on the button, but I can't find a way to do it

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>toggle</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("btn btn-success btn btn-info btn btn-primary");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #p {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <button id="p" class="btn btn-success">Random button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected result of that `.toggleClass("btn btn-success btn btn-info btn btn-primary")` call? Why is `btn` three times in there?

Comment: Looks like you're misunderstanding what "toggleClass" does. It's essentially: `foreach (var b in buttons) { foreach (var cls in buttonClasses) { if (b.hasClass(cls) b.removeClass(cls) else b.addClass(cls) } }`.   It's not "add class back *if* it was removed earlier"  Have a look at this quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/6qw90vgo/

Comment: @freedomn-m oh thanks for the explanation but then what do I need to reach the result i need?

Comment: Bit hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but looks like you're trying to toggle class btn-xxx - is that right?

Comment: yes i am trying to toggle between multiple btn classes to change the look of the button i am clicking each time i do it

Comment: So what you mean is, the button should be green by default, when you click on it, it should change to the info color and when clicked again, it should turn blue, etc.?

Comment: Do you mean *cycle* through them?  btn-success->btn-info->btn-primary->btn-success ?   Or btn-success->(not btn-success)->btn-success while btn-info->(not btn-info)->btn-info

Comment: @ruleboy21 yes exacly

Comment: @freedomn-m i want to loop through them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the classes you want to apply into an array and store the array index of the currently applied class in a variable or using jQuery's `.data()` method.

Then, whenever the button is clicked, you retrieve and increase the index to get the next class and apply it to the button. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classes = ['btn-success', 'btn-info', 'btn-primary'];

    $("button").click(function(){
        let idx = $(this).data('class-index') ?? 0; // index of the currently applied class
        let cls = classes[idx+1] ?? classes[0]; // get the next class
        $(this).data('class-index', classes.indexOf(cls)); // store the class index
        $(this).removeClass(classes).addClass(cls); // remove old class and apply new one
    });
});
```

```css
button { outline: none!important; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="p" class="btn btn-success">Random button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could increment a counter each time the button is clicked and add a class based on the count. 0 = green, 1 = red. Toggle is only for switching between two states like a physical toggle would

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).